# Connecting to MongoDB from azure function

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-functions

I have a problem connecting to a MongoDB from a C# function running on microsoft azure. The function is time triggered, it should collect some data from MongoDB and put them to storage queue.

I have added mongoDB dependencies to the to project.json and this is what the file looks like:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "MongoDB.Bson": "2.4.2",
        "MongoDB.Driver": "2.4.2",
        "MongoDB.Driver.Core": "2.4.2",
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when i call:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(conn));
settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

I get an error after the last line is called:

```
mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. MongoDB.Driver.Core: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've checked and .net version is 4.6 so there should be no problem with that. Is there anything else I am missing.

Comment: Why do you need an interop dependency for the mongodb driver?

Comment: MongoDB.Driver.Core has a dependency to interop. Why? i really have no idea. That is the question for the developers of the driver.

Comment: And also i've tried adding a completely new function that will directly refference the required assemblies, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been digging a bit through their JIRA issues and found [JIRA ISSUE](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1807?jql=project%20%3D%20CSHARP%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Connectivity%20ORDER%20BY%20status%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC). I've reverted the `MongoDB.Driver` `MongoDB.Driver.Core` and `MongoDB.Bson` to a version 2.3.0 and it work like a fine tuned watch, so it seems to be the problem with the Mongo package itself.

I've tested it with the different versions of the package and the issue is introduced in the version 2.4.0. All the previous versions work well.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that was the cause. I made a nuget package for Azure functions if anybody is interested :  https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureMongoRepository.AzureFunctions

Comment: You are my lord and savior bless you

Comment: how do we add nuget libraries in azure portal? I am facing similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144242/error-cs0006-metadata-file-mongodb-could-not-be-found

Comment: If someone had the same issue with JavaScript, you have to use JS Mongo DB driver and you can find a working code example in [here](https://medium.com/@nuwanprabhath/sending-messages-from-azure-iot-hub-to-cosmos-db-using-azure-functions-javascript-717d84f8d922) showing how to install required dependencies.