# Azure Function with Cosmos MongoDB integration not saving

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have setup a Azure Function with a Azure Cosmos DB(document) output. The cosmos database is configured to be a MongoDB.
And added the following simple code to try and add a new document:

```
module.exports = function (context, eventHubMessages) {
   context.bindings.document = {
   text : "Test data"
}   
context.done();
};
```

When i test run i get success, but when i try to open the the collection using Studio 3T i get:

```
Query failed with error code 1 and error message 'Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.'
```

When i use the same code to write to a DocumentDB i get success and i can view data in Azure. Do you need to use a different API to save data to mongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

The DocumentDB output binding is using the [DocumentDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-introduction) to connect and save information in the database. But your database (from what you are saying) is using the [MongoDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction), they are different APIs (links point to the docs).

As you surely know, MongoDB has some requirements (like the existence of an "_id" attribute) that are covered when you connect to the database from a MongoDB client (either an SDK or a third-party client), but since you are communicating through the DocumentDB API, it's probably failing to fulfill those requirements.

You might want to try and use the [Mongo driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045678/connecting-to-mongodb-from-azure-function) in the function to connect to your Cosmos DB database through the MongoDB API.

Comment: Yes, this is a rather undocumented issue for azure functions at the moment.  I created a new database, this time with the SQL driver, and it worked. However, this does not suit my use case as we really needed the mongodb API.

Comment: You can use JS [mongo db driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) to do this. [Here](https://medium.com/@nuwanprabhath/sending-messages-from-azure-iot-hub-to-cosmos-db-using-azure-functions-javascript-717d84f8d922) is an article on how to install dependencies to Azure Functions and sample code. Hope this helps