# Output bindings not picked up or present in Javascript Azure Functions

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm having a bit of difficulty getting my simple Azure Function to dump a JSON payload into a CosmosDB. Here is the desired setup:

```
[HTTP TRIGGER] -> [JS FUNCTION] -> [INSERT JSON TO COSMOS DB]
```

I've added a cosmosDB output binding via **Integrate** in the web console

[image]

I know this part works because it will auto-create the collection upon running.

However, this is where my success ends.

I've included my code here. Maybe there is something obvious that I have missed:

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "outDatabase",
      "collectionName": "MyCollection",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connection": "mydocdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    context.bindings.outputDocument = {test: "hello world"}
    context.done();
};
```

**snippet output of context.log(context)**
I've also peeked into the context variables, and it seems that the outbund bindings not there. I would have expected to see outputDocument here:

```
bindings: 
   { req: 
      { originalUrl: 'https://log-ugly-url-here',
        method: 'POST',
        query: [Object],
        headers: [Object],
        body: [Object],
        params: {},
        rawBody: '{\n    "name": "Azure"\n}' } },
  bind: [Function],
```

Executing this function in the portal gets a 200 OK, but no values show up in my cosmosdb collections.

No errors are shown anywhere.

Can anyone see what I might have missed?

**Updates**
It was recommended that I try to use JSON.stringify() around the payload, per [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb#documentdb-api-output-binding-sample):

```
context.bindings.outputDocument = JSON.stringify({test: "hello world"});
```

However, this has not resolved the issue. I've noticed that the documentation under the binding config sections does not recommend this strategy.

**Update - Nov. 8, 2017 (10:12 AM)**

I was using the Data Explorer blade in azure to see if there were results in my collections. I decided to use Robo 3T Mongo client. Now, when I query the collection I get the following error:

```
Error: error: {
    "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 1,
    "errmsg" : "Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.",
    "$err" : "Unknown server error occurred when processing this request."
}
```

I tried to look at the logs for this cosmosdb, but no errors show up.

Comment: Based on the example in this doc it appears the DocDB binding from javascript expects a string (in a `JSON.stringify()`).  Let me know if that works. [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb#documentdb-api-output-binding-sample)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately that did not work either. I'm updating the original question with different strategies until we get this solved.

Comment: Your initial code works just fine for me, I got the "hello world" document inserted. `context.log(context)` is the same, so it's not a problem. Just in case: the document gets auto-generated ID, maybe you just don't see it?

Comment: @Mikhail thanks for trying it out. I've updated the question again with output from my mongo client (Robo 3T).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Function with Cosmos MongoDB integration not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145356/azure-function-with-cosmos-mongodb-integration-not-saving)

Comment: Was your database created with MongoDB connectivity?

Comment: Yes, it was. I tried a different database with SQL API, and this worked. Therefore, we will simply punt and just make an Azure function to dump data into a postgres database. Thanks to all for the help on this one.

Comment: Next time mention this in your question ;) Have you tried setting all the attributes required by Mongo, like `_id`?

Comment: Doesn't the mongo id have to be an ObjectID? I'm not sure it can just be an arbitrary random string.

Comment: Speaking of stringify, there was an issue opened recently relating to JSON formatting in node.js functions. Note sure if it's your issue but might be worth looking into: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2111. This customer was also trying to post JSON to MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well. Kept banging my head until I saw this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb

“At this time, the Azure Cosmos DB trigger, input bindings, and output bindings work with SQL API and Graph API accounts only“

Looks like there is a bug in Azure that accidentally corrupts the database.