# Error while trying to bind Azure Function to CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I want to connect my Azure Function with my CosmosDB collection using DocumentDB output binding.

My Function:

```cs
public static class HttpTriggerSave
{
    [FunctionName("HttpTriggerSave")]
    public static void Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, [DocumentDB("dbName", "collectionName", Id = "id")] dynamic outputDoc, TraceWriter log)
    {
        outputDoc = new
        {
            Text = "text",
            id = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
    }
}
```

My local.settings.json

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://<namespace>/;SharedAccessKeyName=<keyname>;SharedAccessKey=<key>",
    "AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString": "mongodb://..."
  }
}
```

However I get every time the same error:

```
mscorlib: Exception while executing function: HttpTriggerSave. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'outputDoc'. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: authKeyOrResourceToken.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: It looks like you're using a Mongo connection string. I'm not sure that this is supported yet for Azure functions

Comment: You might need to change the attribute as below. This sample is to read when a new doc is added [FunctionName("FunctionName")]

publicstaticasync Task Run(

  [CosmosDBTrigger("dbname", "collection", ConnectionStringSetting = "Cosmos")] IReadOnlyList<Document> changeList,

        TraceWriter log)



You of course also need this NuGet package: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB  More updates in the below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Function with Cosmos MongoDB integration not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46145356/5641598)

Comment: @Baskar The `CosmosDBTrigger` attribute must be used when I want to trigger the function in response to database changes. I want to do the opposite: I want to bind the function to CosmosDB so that I can modify the database within the function assigning the new document to `outputDoc` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> mscorlib: Exception while executing function: HttpTriggerSave. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'outputDoc'. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: authKeyOrResourceToken.

According to the exception, it indicates that it has no access to Documentdb. According to your local.settings.json that you use the MongoDb connection string.

So please use the documentdb connection string.

```
AccountEndpoint=https://{documentDbName}.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=xxxxx;
```

And I also do a demo on my side, it works correctly.

```
 [FunctionName("HttpTriggerSave")]
 public static void Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,[DocumentDB("tomdb", "collectionId")] out dynamic outputDoc, TraceWriter log)
 {
    outputDoc = new
    {
          Text = "text",
          Id= Guid.NewGuid()
    };
  }
```

[image]

Comment: following this i got rid of the error but now i am getting
"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, ..."
i put a detailed question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822472/azure-function-is-giving-not-a-valid-base-64-string-error
if you could help please

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with a similar error while trying to connect to Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB. This [GitHub article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33312) helped me realize that I couldn't bind in the same way as I would to a SQL database in my NodeJs app. Rather, I leveraged the NPM package, [mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

My version of the error read like this:

`Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'authKeyOrResourceToken | secureAuthKey').`