# Azure function is giving not a valid Base-64 string error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a http-trigger with a CosmosDB output binding and a simplest of a function as below.

```
 public static class AddRequest
{
    [FunctionName("AddRequest")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log, [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "haveThatDB",
            collectionName: "Requests",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "MongoDBEndPoint",CreateIfNotExists =true)] IAsyncCollector<Request> requestOutput
       )

    {
       string jsonContent = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

        await requestOutput.AddAsync(data);

        return req != null
           ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, ras")
           : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}
```

when i executed i get an error

> Exception binding parameter 'requestOutput'. System.Private.CoreLib: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters

[image]

i am using V2 of azure functions.

i have observed that removing the output binding works. so looks like something is up with this output binding.

local.settings contents are as below

> {
>     "IsEncrypted": false,
>     "Values": {
>       "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
>       "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
>     "MongoDBEndPoint": "AccountEndpoint=https://abc.documents.azure.com:10255;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzz",
>       "MongoDBName": "haveThatDB"
>     }
>   }

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Cosmos DB bindings are only supported for use with the SQL API. For all other Azure Cosmos DB APIs, you should access the database from your function by using the static client for your API, including MongoDB API, Cassandra API, Gremlin API, and Table API. 
[Supported APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#supported-apis)

[Azure Cosmos DB bindings for Azure Functions 2.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2)

Comment: i switched to sql api and now i am getting
"'Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 1, position 1.'"
i dont get this error locally  in VS but i get this when i hit deployed url using postman. 
if i remove the ourput binding it works.

Comment: You are using Functions v2? There are a bunch if issues with v2 and there some specific configurations you need to implement. See the following: Azure Functions Runtime 2.0 breaking changes - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-functions-runtime-2-0-breaking-change-notice/

Comment: Azure Functions Runtime 2.0.12050-alpha breaking changes notice - https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129

Comment: i have  Runtime version: 2.0.12134.0 (~2)  not sure if this document is applicable here ?