# Azure function output binding destroys collection in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I am trying to save a document to a collection in CosmosDB using output binding.

The DB was created with MongoDB API access.

I noticed a few issues:

1. Azure function in JavaScript with output binding doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```js
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    if (req.body) {
        context.bindings.outputObject = JSON.stringify({
            name: "Mike P"
        }); // tried outputObjectOut as well, no difference

        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

The **function.json** for the JavaScript code is the same as given further below.

2. I wrote equivalent code in C# and noticed that the collection was destroyed (by the binding apparently when the document was saved).

```cs
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req,
    out object outputObject, TraceWriter log)
{
    outputObject = new {
        name = "Mike P"
    };

    log.Info("test");

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Here is the function.json

```js
{
  "type": "documentDB",
  "name": "outputObject",
  "databaseName": "newexp",
  "collectionName": "Test",
  "createIfNotExists": true,
  "connection": "newexp_DOCUMENTDB",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

The collection can't be queried any more in the Azure console. Querying through a MongoDB client like 3T failed as well.

I would expect this code to work and a document shows up in the collection in the DB. But instead I am seeing the collection becoming unusable. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145356/azure-function-with-cosmos-mongodb-integration-not-saving/46154139#46154139

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Function CosmosDB binding is written against the DocumentDB API (or SQL API) for CosmosDB - so doesn't work out-of-the-box with Mongo API. I believe it may work if you add a required _id property in the object. Without an _id field the Mongo API call will fail

Comment: Thanks much @jeffhollan. I just tried adding _id field to the object and I still get an error from the mongo client. Perhaps I can't use bindings if I want to keep it readable by a mongo client. I am researching further and will post an update with my findings.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I suspect you will have to switch away from bindings and use native Mongo client

Comment: I was able to resolve this. You have to use Mongo DB driver for JS to do this. You can find an article [here](https://medium.com/@nuwanprabhath/sending-messages-from-azure-iot-hub-to-cosmos-db-using-azure-functions-javascript-717d84f8d922) describing how to install dependencies and working sample code.