# Cosmos Mongodb query fails but azure storage explorer works fine?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query a Cosmos MongoDB collection, I can connect to it fine with Robo3T and 3T Studio, and dotnet core mongo client (in a test harness).  I can do a count of entities (db.[collection_name].count({})) in all of the platforms, but every query (db.[collection_name].find({}) fails with the following error :

```
Error: error: {
"_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 1,
"errmsg" : "Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.",
"$err" : "Unknown server error occurred when processing this request."}
```

Here is my sample query from Rob3T and below that sample .NET harness.. Doesn't matter what I use, same error every time.

```
db.wihistory.find({})
```

and the dotnet core code :

```
string connectionString = @"my connections string here";
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
            new MongoUrl(connectionString)
        );
        settings.SslSettings = 
        new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("vstsagileanalytics");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<dynamic>("wihistory");
        var data = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
        System.Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
```

Comment: We don't see this in any other account we know. Could you send the <accountname>.documents.azure.com to askcosmosmongoapi@microsoft.com ?

Comment: You mentioned that you are using Azure Storage Explorer, did you insert any document using that tool or any other tool that uses the DocumentDB SDK / SQL API?

Comment: We are using Azure Functions to act as a webhook with VSTS updates to Work Items to do some cross account analytics with VSTS... In that we are using the same Mongo API..

We haven't used any other method of inserting data than the Azure Function.

and @aleskey I am sending you that info now.

Comment: Oh and PowerBI has no problem pulling the data, so our BI guys are doing some mockups on the analytics they want with that, but its not a great long term solution for our need.

Comment: last comment for the moment : Data Explorer also throws {"code":500,"body":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} when trying to run on the collection

Comment: Josh, the both errors are related (Data Explorer and Robo3T). Data Explorer uses internally a Mongo client to connect and runs the same `find` command. You say you work with Azure Functions, are you using the [Output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#output)?

Comment: yes. I am using the output bindings 
here is my method signature: 

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, out object outputDocument)

so I populate the outputDocument and return a 200 response to the client.

Comment: I also let the Azure Function (and the integration to DocumentDB) create the database and collection for me (its a checkbox) so that it would configure it correctly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from mixing API usage in the account. As stated in the comments, you are using [Azure Function's Cosmos DB Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#output), which uses the SQL API ([.NET SDK for SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet)) to connect to the account and store data. There is a **note** in that documentation that says:

> Don't use Azure Cosmos DB input or output bindings if you're using
>   MongoDB API on a Cosmos DB account. Data corruption is possible.

The documents stored through this method do not enforce certain MongoDB requirements (like the existence of a "_id" identifier) that a MongoDB client would (a MongoDB client would automatically create the "_id" if not present).

Robo3T and other Mongo clients (including the Azure Portal) are failing to correctly parse and read the stored documents as valid MongoDB documents (due to the lack of requirements like "_id") and that is the cause of the error.

You can either switch to use a Cosmos DB SQL API account if you want to maintain the Azure Functions pipeline or change the output binding and replace it with a manual implementation of a [MongoDB client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045678/connecting-to-mongodb-from-azure-function).

Comment: No worries, we added that note for this particular scenario. Let us know if we can assist further.