# Cosmos DB and Azure.iOS data query issues

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm fairly new to Cosmos DB so for starters I created a MongoDB based instance. I then wanted to add a document to it, just as a "Hello World" test. I'm using a self made iOS app for this which uses the official [Azure.iOS](https://github.com/Azure/Azure.iOS) library from GitHub.

Once I run the "create" command (with the proper collection id set) on AzureData the framework returns me a "success" inside the response with a resource id etc. However once I use an external tool such as Robo3T or the mongo shell the given collection is said to be empty, or returns this error:

`{"code":400,"body":"Command find failed: Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.."}`

The connection to the DB however is successful since I can display the collection stats and so on.

Now if I open my app again and query the collection documents through the Azure.iOS framework it returns me the result I just saved. This makes me feel a bit puzzled. Did I miss doing something inside the app, or do all MongoDB tools fail listing the documents? The documentation for the framework is rather sparse so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please verify what region you are in?

Comment: I'm in Europe and that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue that happened for me is very hard to debug. Since the error messages don't tell anything.

My Cosmos DB is using the MongoDB backend which seems to create issues together with the mentioned Azure.iOS framework.

The issue is further described here:
[Cosmos Mongodb query fails but azure storage explorer works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48403270/4591036)

TL;DR what happened is that the iOS framework was not creating a "_id" which is necessary for MongoDB and that lead to corrupted data. I had to switch from MongoDB to the SQL backend. This solved my issue and now everything works fine.

Comment: Tell me more about what you did, I'm having the same problem

Comment: I basically switched the backend from Mongo to SQL, then it worked.