# Error CS0006: Metadata file 'MongoDB' could not be found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have created a `Azure Function` and it has below code in `run.csx'

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using MongoDB.Bson.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");
 }
```

I am having `Project.json` as follow

```
  {
    "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
    "dependencies": {
      "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.3",
      "System.ServiceModel.Primitives":"4.4.0",
      "MongoDB.Bson": "2.4.0",
      "MongoDB.Driver": "2.4.0",
      "MongoDB.Driver.Core": "2.4.0"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I am getting below error while running the azure function

> 2019-01-11T10:01:14.846 [Error] run.csx(5,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> 2019-01-11T10:01:15.108 [Error] run.csx(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I even tried adding namespace like below but no luck

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Xml"
#r "System.Xml.Linq" 
#r "MongoDB"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caused by the difference of Function runtime.

`project.json` is used for functions on ~1 runtime where code targets at .NET Framework, while the function you create is on ~2 runtime which runs on .NET Core env. When we create a new Function app its runtime is set to ~2 by default now.

So the solution is simple, delete existing functions in the Function app and change Function runtime version to ~1(Find it in portal, Platform features>Function app settings). Then you could recreate an IoT Hub (Event Hub) trigger with steps above, things should work this time.

To work with Function 2.0, use `function.proj` to install packages.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="<packageName>" Version="<version>"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Since ~2 runtime is latest, then I feel it's better to use it. but where I can find the documentation to acheive the same functionality using ~2 runtime?

Comment: @kudlatiger See my update to install packages in ~2 runtime.